Which is the cost of `div` in Haskell?
I'm trying to calculate the cost of a function izq where I use the function div inside:
izq n   | even (n - 1)  = ((n - 1) `div` 2)
        | otherwise     = (((n - 1) `div` 2) + 1)

So work of izq is 1 + the cost of div applied to (n - 1). However, I'm unsure about the cost of div. Does anyone know the typical cost of the div function in Haskell?

'div' 2 might have a very different cost to 'div' x in general.

(`div` 2) is for postive numbers equivalent to (`shiftR` 2).

Err, shift by one. Not two.

What do you mean by "the cost"? In what units? How do you conclude that the cost of the function overall is exactly 1 more than the cost of a div operation? The function seems to do more than one other thing.

For Ints, x `div` 2 is usually implemented as a single instruction.  If you compile:
div2 :: Int -> Int
div2 x = x `div` 2

with ghc -Wall -O2 -fforce-recomp -ddump-asm with GHC 9.6.4, you'll get the assembly below, to which I've added some annotations.  Of the 23 or so instructions, the (`div` 2) itself is implemented by a single instruction in the .LcZw block.
sarq $1,%rax                         ;; *** SHIFT ARITHMETIC RIGHT BY ONE BIT ***

In the context of your izq function -- again, assuming it's izq :: Int -> Int -- the situation is similar.  For the even branch, the actual calculation of (n-1) `div` 2 is implemented in two assembly instructions:
decq %rax
sarq $1,%rax

while for the odd branch, it takes three:
decq %rax
sarq $1,%rax
incq %rax

The cost of the even/odd check itself is rather expensive, apparently due to a bug in the even implementation.  Replace it with your own (e.g., even' x = x `mod` 2 == 0), and you'll get better assembly.
;; even/odd check using `even` function (ick!)
leaq -1(%rax),%rbx
movq %rbx,%rcx
shrq $63,%rcx
movq %rbx,%rdx
addq %rcx,%rdx
andq $-2,%rdx
subq %rdx,%rbx
testq %rbx,%rbx
jne .Lc13I             ;; jump if odd

;; even/odd check using: even' x = x `mod` 2 == 0
leaq -1(%rax),%rbx
andl $1,%ebx
testq %rbx,%rbx
jne .Lc15b

If izq is inlined in a block of performant code, you can assume that the entire function will be boiled down to the 14 or so instructions listed above, and that the incremental cost of the div will be one instructions.
But, a better way to think of it is that the cost of div is almost nothing, and if you are trying to write some high performance code, you should do lots of profiling and look for improvements other than replacing div.
The assembly generated by div2:
.section .text
.align 8
.align 8
    .quad   4294967301
    .quad   0
    .long   14
    .long   0
.globl FastDiv.div2_info
.type FastDiv.div2_info, @function
FastDiv.div2_info:
.LcZm:
    leaq -8(%rbp),%rax                   ;; check for sufficient stack space
    cmpq %r15,%rax
    jb .LcZt                             ;; ...if not, handle it
.LcZu:
    movq $.Lblock_cZj_info,-8(%rbp)      ;; push continuation for `div 2` operation on stack
    movq %r14,%rbx
    addq $-8,%rbp
    testb $7,%bl                         ;; check if argument is evaluated
    jne .LcZj                            ;; skip to continuation if it is
.LcZk:
    jmp *(%rbx)                          ;; otherwise, evaluate argument
.align 8
    .quad   0
    .long   30
    .long   0
.Lblock_cZj_info:                            ;; continuation for `div 2` starts here
.LcZj:
    addq $16,%r12                        ;; allocate 16 bytes on the heap
    cmpq 856(%r13),%r12                  ;; if not enough room...
    ja .LcZx                             ;; ...do a garbage collection
.LcZw:
    movq 7(%rbx),%rax                    ;; get the integer payload from the argument
    sarq $1,%rax                         ;; *** SHIFT ARITHMETIC RIGHT BY ONE BIT ***
    movq $GHC.Types.I#_con_info,-8(%r12) ;; add the constructor for boxed integers to the heap object
    movq %rax,(%r12)                     ;; add the result of the shift to the heap object
    leaq -7(%r12),%rbx                   ;; get a pointer to the heap object
    addq $8,%rbp                         ;; clean up the stack
    jmp *(%rbp)                          ;; call our continunation to pass the result along
.LcZx:
    movq $16,904(%r13)                   ;; handle insufficient heap space
    jmp stg_gc_unpt_r1
.LcZt:
    leaq FastDiv.div2_closure(%rip),%rbx ;; handle insufficient stack space
    jmp *-8(%r13)
    .size FastDiv.div2_info, .-FastDiv.div2_info


Oops.  I intended to write mod.  It should be fixed now.

A single divMod might be better.
